# Can I have my Window exe (with a GUI) expose a COM interface

Tags: c#, wpf, com

I have a C# based windows exe using a WPF GUI. My GUI app. polls another window service every minute running on same machine for some updates. Can i expose a COM interface into my WPF GUI exe so that i can remove polling and instead window service make a COM call into the WPF GUI exe app to provide updates?

Answer (score 0):

You probably could, but why COM? You could just as well use .NET communication technologies like Remoting or WCF.

That said, it's usually better to let the UI client initiate the communication to the Windows service and not the other way around. Mainly because you can have multiple client apps running (if more than one user is logged on to the machine).

Comment: i have a situation where only one client app is running on one piece of hardware. Also in my case i have multiple window services that notify each other through COM calls. Only exception is with the GUI. I want to make it consistent across the whole application.